# Can I initialize a SIM card when abroad?

Tags: france, cellphones, mobile-operators, roaming, gsm-mobile

I will be travelling from France to Germany / Poland / Austria later this month and I will have a French **new** SIM card shipped to me when I will be abroad.

**Is it possible to initialize such a card on a foreign (roaming) network without the card having been in a phone in the country it was issued from?** (if it matters, the card will be from the Frech provider *Free Mobile*).

Notes:

- the card has roaming enabled
- I can "activate" the card remotely on the company web site. "Activate" means "flip a switch which will make it allowed to get into the network at all"
- it will not be opened in France (I need the package to be intact - not because I am a bandit of some sort but because, long story, this is what I need)

Comment: Worst case scenario you activate it when landing in France.

Comment: @JonathanReez: yes of course. I wanted to use it when travelling, though.

Comment: I have done the same thing (not in Europe) and it worked. Why don't you ask Free Mobile themselves? +33 1 78 56 95 60

Comment: @Newton: the support of Free Mobile is dreadful. I will get somebody who will explain me what roaming is. When i ask again, that I will not be charged more for the roaming. And if I ask a third time they will provide me a list of phones which are compatible with a nano SIM.

Comment: It depends on the carrier.  Some will only activate on native service.  On the other hand, I personally have activated UK (GiffGaff) and US (T-Mobile) SIMs while in Canada.  So... maybe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I went through some contacts and I got an answer form an engineer who oversees the roaming (at another provider's). Her answer is

> yes, the card needs to be active on the local (national) network at least once so that it is registered with the HLR (Home Location Register). It then can roam.

I will take it as an authoritative answer.